# Aligning Search bar with other elements in the nav

Tags: html, css, frontend, searchbar, web-frontend

I previously asked a question about shifting the search bar on the right most side of my navigation bar, following the answers I did successfully shift it to the right, However now the search bar is not in-line with the other elements (Previously it was). Which CSS Property (if any) is preventing it from happening and what could be the solution?

Code :

```css
body
    {
     margin: 0;
     background: #222;
     font-weight: 300;
     background-image: url('logo.jpeg');
    }
    
    .container
    {
     width: 80%;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    header
    {
     background: #f3e5ab;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    header::after
    {
     content: '';
     display: table;
     clear: both;
    }
    
    nav
    {
     float: left;
    }
    
    nav ul
    {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
    }
    
    nav li
    {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 70px;
     padding-top: 30px;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    nav ul li  a
    {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    nav a:hover
    {
    
    }
    
    
    nav a::before
    {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     height: 5px;
     width: 0%;
     background-color: #444;
    
     transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
    
    
    }
    nav a:hover::before
    {
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    form .form
    {
     float: right;
    }
    
    .search-bar
    {
     float: right;
    }
    
    ul li:last-child
    {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    
    }
```

```html
<header>
     <div class="container">
      <nav>
       <ul> 
        <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Services </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Products </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
            <li> <form class="form"> <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search"> </form> </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say I am on the same page as far as it goes to the general layout and approach you chose, but here is a quick fix (if I understood correctly your issue)

https://codepen.io/magom001/pen/mXwovO?editors=1100

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
    font-weight: 300;
    background-image: url('logo.jpeg');
}

.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  displayt: table;
  clear: both;
}

header
{
    background: #f3e5ab;
    position: relative;
}

header::after
{
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

nav
{
    float: left;
}

nav ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li  a
{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 14px;
}

nav a:hover
{

}


nav a::before
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;

    transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;


}
nav a:hover::before
{
    width: 100%;
}

form .form
{
    float: right;
}

.search-bar
{
    float: right;
}

ul li:last-child
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: 15px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding: 0;

}
```

Just change top:0 to bottom: 0 and remove margin-bottom on the last-child.